# Compare data with ajax response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have Script is as below

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').find('.tree').fadeOut(0);

   $('.tree-title').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
   contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType : "json",
   url : "loadSubFolders",
   type : 'GET',
   data : {
    id : id
   },
   success : function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
      response.push('<li class="tree-title" id='+value.folderId+'>'+value.folderName+'</li>');
      alert("Appended Successfully");
    });
    $('.tree').append( response.join('') );
   },
   error : function(res, textStatus) {
    var msg = "Unable to load Subfolder";
    alert(msg);
   }
  });
        setStatus($(this));
    });
});
```

In this I want to compare data means `id` to some response element like

```js
success : function(response) {
      $.each(response, function(index, value) {
     if(id==value.rootId){
    response.push('<li class="tree-title" id='+value.folderId+'>'+value.folderName+'</li>');
     alert("Appended Successfully");
     }
   else{
    response.push('<li class="tree-title" ></li>');
    alert("Append Failed");
     }
   });
    $('.tree').append( response.join('') );
},
```

But it s not working

How could i achieve this? Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: What issue you are facing in this?

Comment: can you explain more specify? compare again with what?

Comment: in ajax response list is there and i have id which is ajax data so now after getting ajax response i want to check that data with response as list element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply properties to your success callback and access them from within the closure using `this`. Example `this.id` The custom properties you specify can't already be defined in the `ajax` prototype, otherwise you'll rewrite the default values. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').find('.tree').fadeOut(0);

   $('.tree-title').click(function () {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "loadSubFolders",
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                id : id
            },
            id : id,
            success : function(response) {
                afterSuccess(response , this.id);

                function afterSuccess(data, i) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        if(i==value.rootId){
                            data.push('<li class="tree-title" id='+value.folderId+'>'+value.folderName+'</li>');
                            alert("Appended Successfully");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Append Failed");
                        }
                    });
                    $('.tree').append( data.join('') );
                }
            }
        });
        setStatus($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: what does `console.log(this.id);` output when placed inside your success callback? Is it defined? Is `value.rootId` defined?

Comment: define alert(this.id) and works properly outside of each loop but didn't get value.rootId.

Comment: Sorry you may have to append `this.id` to your response object since you are using `$.each` to iterate over it. Or optionally create a partial function supplying your custom parameter as an argument inside your success callback and call that function within your the `$.each` function

Comment: Well then there is a problem with `value.rootId`. I would first check to see what your `response` is using `console.log(response)` then find out how to access its properties.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `response` may be returning the outer container of JSON. You may have better luck with something like `$.each(response[0], function(i,val){...})` Or something along those lines.

Comment: Because I don't know what's in your response, I can't really help very much further on this

Comment: Response is getting properly I have all values of response element now console.log(this.id) is not working inside the each loop but it works outside the each loop can you give some about this

Comment: Try `response.thisID = id` then `$.each(response, function(index,value){...});`

Comment: I've made an update to my answer. Please see if that works for your use case. If so could you mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could load your results into a separate variable like `contents`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').find('.tree').fadeOut(0);

   $('.tree-title').click(function () {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "loadSubFolders",
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                id : id
            },
            id : id,
            success : function(response) {
                afterSuccess(response , this.id);
                function afterSuccess(data, i) {
                    var contents = "";
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        if(i==value.rootId){
                            contents += '<li class="tree-title" id='+value.folderId+'>'+value.folderName+'</li>';
                            alert("Appended Successfully");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Append Failed");
                        }
                    });
                    $('.tree').append( contents );
                }
            }
        });
        setStatus($(this));
    });
});
```